# Certbot pluging development - How to get command line arguments

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm developing a plugin for Certbot and I need to get some parameters from user when they run the plugin. I searched in the docs and couldn't find a way to get params to the plugin code. My plugin contains only an Authenticator. Plugin code is similar to below,

```
@zope.interface.implementer(interfaces.IAuthenticator)
@zope.interface.provider(interfaces.IPluginFactory)
class Authenticator(common.Plugin):

    def prepare(self):
      pass

    def get_chall_pref(self, domain):
      return [challenges.HTTP01]

   def perform(self, achalls):
     param = #need to get param here

   def cleanup(self, achalls):
     self.reverter.recovery_routine()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Authenticator(common.Plugin):

    @classmethod
    def add_parser_arguments(cls, add):
      add('server-url', help='url or ip of the server')

    def perform(self, achalls):
      param = self.conf('server-url')
```

As in the above code, `add_parser_arguments` methd is comming from `IPlugin` interface. In that method we can define what arguments that our plugin needs and can give an description to it. 
Then can use it as the `perform` function uses it